# Is it possible to know whether wear device is on wrist?

Tags: java, android, wear-os

I want to know if it's possible to know whether wear device is on hand or not.
I need to run a service who take pulse only when it's on hand, then if it's not, then it should stop service and start it again when it's on hand.

Comment: Nothing...cause I don't know how I can start/stop that service base on wrist detection :(...I have only a service that is running for ever

Comment: I think you will need a sensor for this

Comment: I know that, but I don't know what kind of sensor?

Comment: Then search for sensor

Comment: You can't do this based on a straight up Android sensor w/o a continuous service (that  requires keeping a listener), but you could just wake up the device every X minutes w/ a job as it's not *that* inefficient.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using heart rate sensor

```
public class MainActivity extends WearableActivity implements SensorEventListener {

    private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";
    private TextView mTextViewHeart;
    SensorManager mSensorManager;
    Sensor mHeartRateSensor;
    SensorEventListener sensorEventListener;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mTextViewHeart = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.heart);
        mSensorManager = ((SensorManager) getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE));
        mHeartRateSensor = mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_HEART_RATE);
        mSensorManager.registerListener(this, mHeartRateSensor, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
        Log.i(TAG, "LISTENER REGISTERED.");
        mTextViewHeart.setText("Something here");


        mSensorManager.registerListener(sensorEventListener, mHeartRateSensor, mSensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST);
    }


    public void onResume(){
        super.onResume();
    }

    public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onAccuracyChanged - accuracy: " + accuracy);
    }

    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
        if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_HEART_RATE) {
            String msg = "" + (int)event.values[0];
            mTextViewHeart.setText(msg);
            Log.d(TAG, msg);
        }
        else
            Log.d(TAG, "Unknown sensor type");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Some devices like the microsoft band 2 have a sensor specifically used to detect whether the device is worn or not. Depending on the project, you may consider developing for that device